# Knockout catching enter in textbox to achieve the same as with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i'm struggling with a problem using knockoutjs for the first time.

I have a textbox for a search string:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: searchString" id="searchText">
```

and a button:

```
<span data-bind="click: searchButton" id="searchBtn"></span>
```

both binded using knockout using the following script:

```
function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        //-----
        self.searchButton = function () {
            if (self.searchString() != null && self.searchString().length > 3) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "./SearchCustomer/",
                    data: "{'searchString':'" + self.searchString() + "'}",
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        baseShowError("Error");
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var receivedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                        if (receivedResponse.Success) {
                            ko.mapping.fromJS(receivedResponse.Result, {}, self);
                        } else {
                            baseShowError("customer not found");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });

$(function () {
        var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()))';
        var myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, {}, new ViewModel());
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
    });
```

Now i want to catch an enter in the textbox using script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#searchText').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    ...........
                }
            });
        });
```

Only problem is what to enter instead of the dots. I read about unobtrusive event handling but nothing it tried seem te work. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While catching the 'enter' seems a valid solution the answer is much more simple.

instead of binding a click to a button you can bind a submit to a form placed over the 2 elements

solution:
  ViewModel stays the same.

```
<form data-bind="submit: seachButton">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: searchString">
    <span data-bind="click: searchButton"></span>
</form>
```

As you can see the data-bind is added to a new form tag.

(Normally if the button is really of input type button you probably could remove de click binding as wel.....not tested)

Comment: This answer frustrates me. You 'solved' the problem by introducing an unnecessary additional HTML element. And now you have two event paths to handle (did they hit enter somewhere in your form? or did they click the 'searchButton')

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just call your `searchButton` method, like `ViewModel.searchButton();` ?

Comment: tried that and tried ViewModel().searchButton(); but without any succes.

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error? Or method not found? More detail, please.